# How to get SSID name of wifi network via cordova app?

Tags: cordova

I install cordova-plugin-wifiwizard2 then I want to get ssid name of wifi network the android mobile is connected as an alert or want to see as document.write to see it on page
is there any code to test?
Note: it is not necessary to use wifiwizard2 can use another plugin but I want to know how to get SSID name

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out it worked for me. Was trying to figure out how to access the value of a Promise

```
  WifiWizard2.getConnectedSSID().then(function(network) {
      alert(network);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      alert('oops: ', error);
    });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this to say that the above did not work for me. This was the code I used:

```
window.WifiWizard2.getConnectedSSID().then(connectedWifi => {
    console.log(connectedWifi)
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

I believe this is due to Apple deciding that they no longer want developers to get local wifi information on their device for security and location tracking purposes.

Comment: Some time before this was working to me, but with Android 10 it stopped.

Comment: Yep, as I have discovered as well over the last couple of days is that this is not possible with Android 10 and so I used a different solution. I have the user manually input their ssid and password and do the verifying in a different place not on the application that I then get a response from which interacts with my app. Not the best solution, but if you have any other solutions that are cleaner I would love to hear them because I would like a smoother experience.

Comment: I use the network ip which apparently is correct!